# Check instanceof File in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm validating incoming data from client-side to server-side, the client-side is sending a File instance to the server. I want to validate that instance using node.js. Except that node.js throws `TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` when evaluating `myPassedFileInstance instanceof File`.

How can I validate a File instance in node.js?

Comment: Obviously, you can't use `instanceof File` on server side. How are you going to pass `File` from client side? The problem is not myPassedFileInstance valudation but how you intend to use it. What should myPassedFileInstance look like?

Comment: Your `myPassedFileInstance` is not an object.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File` interface is not part of Javascript (node.js), it is belonging to Web APIs. 
[More information about File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

So `File` is not available in your node.js application.

Maybe you can use `content-type` in request's headers to check if the request is certain type of file or stream.